# Get bounding box of WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms, leaflet

Is it possible to request the bounding box of a WMS from GeoServer? 
In my case I have a WMS that I show with `L.TileLayer.WMS` in a Leaflet map. I like to center and zoom my map to the WMS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you check the response of the GetCapabilities request, you'll see that each layer has a Bounding Box property, which gives its extent.

For example, you'll get something like:

```
 <LatLonBoundingBox minx="-123.042" miny="42.251" maxx="-122.772" maxy="42.438" /> 
 <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-123.042" miny="42.251" maxx="-122.772" maxy="42.438" />
```

You will have to parse this yourself, using pure JavaScript Code. Leaflet doesn't have anything for parsing this.

Comment: can you give me a quick demo? I just tried the `getCapabilities` request, it shows the error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=2.0.1&request=GetCapabilities' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` how can I solve this error