# Leaflet get full extent of WMS layer

Tags: leaflet, wms, extents

I need the bounds/full extent of a WMS layer in Leaflet. I don't think `L.TileLayer.WMS` has a `getBounds()` method. I had this issue with `L.ImageOverlay`, and added the functionality via:

```
L.ImageOverlay.include({
    getBounds: function () {
        return this._bounds;
    }
});
```

Is there a solution for `L.TileLayer.WMS`? Or will I have to start parsing the WMS `getCapabilities` request for its `LatLongBoundingBox` or `BoundingBox` elements?

EDIT

I've just found a duplicate: [Get bounding box of WMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89321/get-bounding-box-of-wms). This question is still relevant, since Leaflet 1.0 has since been released.

EDIT 2

[Get bounding box of WMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89321/get-bounding-box-of-wms) does not answer my question - its answer is to parse the `getCapabilities` response manually. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get bounding box of WMS does not answer my question - its answer is to parse the getCapabilities response manually. Is there any other way?

No.

Leaflet does not parse the WMS capabilities document. To my knowledge, there are no Leaflet plugins to achieve this in an automated way. Using the [`wms-client` NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wms-client) be useful to ease up the parsing.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a valid use for this, and not an edge case one. Still, thanks for the authoritative answer.